bump2version: How to use the branchName in the commit message?
I use bump2version and I'd like to use variables in my commit message
my .bumpconfiguration.cfg
[bumpversion]
current_version = 13.3.0
commit = True
message = $(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD): bump commit from {current_version} to {new_version}


[bumpversion:file:VERSION]
search = {current_version}
replace = {new_version}

i'd like to use the branch name, but it is not working.
i tried also to set a variable branchName=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) and then set
message = %branchName: bump
but it doesn't work
